# Spring Boot JAR deployment

Tags: java

I have a Spring Boot Java application with property yaml files located under resources folder.
I packaged it in maven using jar format. But the issue is whenever there's a change required in the yaml file I will have to redeploy the jar file.

Is there any way to build the jar file with the reference to yaml files remain outside of the jar?

Comment: No, just copy application.yaml and put it in the same directory as your-spring-boot-app.jar.

Comment: There's a defined lookup order of application.yaml which means you could package one version as the default in your ja and if you provide one right next to your jar or even point to one via startup parameters that one will override the default. See [External Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.1/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files)